Why is my rank formula giving me a formula error?
I get a "There's a problem with this formula" error for my rank.eq formula and I don't know why. Can someone please help me fix it?
Here is a sample of my table:

I am trying to rank Disbursement Dates in order relative to each other per Transaction account, i.e. for Transaction Account a, rank all the dates from oldest to newest relative to each other for that specific transaction account, then do the same for the next transaction account etc.
=
To identify the first disbursement date I have sorted the table by transaction account and then by date and run this line =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A2)>1, "Duplicate", "1st Disbursement") to determine the first disbursement, but I cannot rank the rest.

RANK.EQ function can only be applied to numeric arguments. You didn't show how you call this function.

not sure how your if(countif(...) formula is helping. With that said, I would nest a filter formula in the rank.eq formula

With your data already in a table and sorted by account and transaction date, here're a couple ways:
Using a helper column with FREQUENCY function - Microsoft Support

FREQUENCY also works with numbers, so we use XMATCH to map the accounts to indices XMATCH(Table1[Acct],Table1[Acct])
add a separate column parallel to the table with the following, in the example it is entered in F2:

=FREQUENCY(XMATCH(Table1[Acct],Table1[Acct]),XMATCH(Table1[Acct],Table1[Acct]))


assuming want to indicate First/Duplicate in a column in your table, add another column to your table and enter this formula in the first cell:

=IF(@$F$2#,"First","Duplicate")

Using MINIFS function - Microsoft Support

add another column to your table with the following in the first cell (change the column titles to match yours):

=IF([@[Txn Date]]= MINIFS([Txn Date],[Acct],[@Acct]),"First","Duplicate")

Here's the result for both, I think the first one might perform better with large dataset:

